# How to avoid reloading large JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a large 40,000 words array loading from a database into a JavaScript/HTML array on every page of our web application... What would be the best way/technology to optimize it? In order to avoid this unnecessary downloads.

1. Somehow keep the array in a cookie and read from there?
2. Use ajax to load the array dynamically only parts that are needed?

What is the common practice?

Answer (score 1):

On modern browsers you can use `sessionStorage` to have it persist during the current session, or `localStorage` to have it hang around between sessions.

NB: both only permit storage of strings - you'll have to serialise the array (e.g. into JSON) and deserialise it on retrieval.

If you want to actually use the word list as a local database with efficient lookup you might also want to investigate `indexedDB`

Answer (score 0):

you can place the data in session and retrieve it, the same can be used in every page with out fetching the same every time.

Thanks & best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the 40k words in all pages then you can use localStorage or sessionStorage. Just keep in mind sessionStorage will delete saved data when the tab/window is closed so the whole array will be downloaded again when the website is opened in new windows/tabs.

If you need only specific parts of the array in different pages I would tidy the array's elements into taxonomy/categories (if you are able to), so that you can download only the needed for a specific section of your application.
This depends on the composition of your array, if it is formed only by words or complex objects. This will help to avoid slow load of your website when it's visited the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is always the same (there is no need to update it), I'd create a js file and then I'd add it to every html page. The browser's cache would do the rest to avoid unnecessary re-loading. Something like:

*big-array.js* file:

```
var myBigArray=[...]
```

In each html file

```
<html>
 ... whatever you need
<script src="/my-path/big-array.js"></script>
...my other scripts here
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit difficult to answer this question properly as to do so would require more information about your hosting environment and what you have access to. If you have a server side language available, such as PHP, you could look at caching which is generally the most efficient way to handle data that is used repeatedly across pages. Perhaps you could post more info about what technologies you have available to you?

Comment: The OP is looking for _client-side_ caching, not server side.

Comment: "In order to avoid this unnecessary downloads".  Also, servers don't tend to need caches for this sort of thing.

Comment: Fair enough Alnitak. Though they did mention Ajax which is why server side could have been an option. However, if I understand you correctly, you are wrong about servers not using  caches for this sort of thing. I have worked on many high traffic websites and caching is regularlly used for this sort of thing.

Comment: Sure, for large enough amounts of data, and if the server side is in a persistent program then chances are the data's in memory anyway.   IMHO there's simply not enough information in the question to even start to hypothecate about potential server-side optimisations (whether caching or otherwise), because that's so dependent on the server side stack.

Comment: Even for small amounts of data. Anything that hits a database to retrieve the same data. Your point about there not being enough information in the question was the point I was making in my answer Alnitak. Maybe I didn't make it obvious enough. :-)

Comment: Well, he clearly _does_ have a server side language (he says the word list is coming out of a database).   It'd be pretty dumb not to _already_ have some sort of persistent copy (I deliberately don't use the word cache) of that word list in memory between pages, unless it happens he's using something dumb like CGI (whether PHP or not) where each page load is handled by invoking a whole new executable with no persistent state.

Comment: Oh, and clarifying comments like that (i.e. "not enough information") are supposed to be in comments, not in answers.

Comment: The word list is coming from a database but that doesn't mean he has access to the server side. It could be a restful service or other API that is providing the array.

Comment: I agree with you about comments instead of answers but I don't have enough reputation points to post comments Alnitak. Sorry.